# Change "ActionBar" color doesn't give the correct color

Tags: android

I am trying to change ActionBar color in my "AppBar Layout" programmatically, through this code:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(R.color.hidden_bars); //#464445
```

but every time I end with different color, a darker version of the colorPrimary (#48bee6)

Here is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        style="@style/WenoTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_bar_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: check colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark in your App Theme which will be present in style.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding of `setBackgroundColor(int)`. The int value pass to `setBackgroundColor` should be color code instead of color resource id. You should get the color code by id first.

```
// Use this instead of context if you are in activity
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);   
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color);
```